# Rails Devise error on building one to one relationship upon registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I want to create a one to one relationship, User -> Account upon Devise registration. I thought I had it figured out with the following code.

```
# account.rb
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :account
end

# registrations_controller.rb
def create
  super
  current_user.build_account(account_params).save
end
```

And this code works about 80% of the time so far. But every once and a while, I get the following error.

`undefined method 'build_account' for nil:NilClass
 app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:13:in 'create'`

Clearly, the error is telling me, you cannot `build_account` when `current_user` is `nil`. That makes sense to me, but

1. Why does that happen only some of the time?
2. What is a more consistent way to build this one to one relationship upon Devise user registration?

Comment: How is your `current_user` look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I do this I like to use nested forms.

```
# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :account
end

# account.rb
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

#views registrations/new.html.haml
  = simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|
  %ul
    - resource.errors.full_messages.each do |e|
      %li=e
        = f.simple_fields_for :account do |account_form|
          ...
        ...


#Controller
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    resource = build_resource({})
    resource.build_account
    respond_with resource
  end

  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)
    if resource.save
      ...
    else
      ...
     end
   end

   private
   def sign_up_params
     allow = [:first_name, :last_name, :phone, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :agree_newsleter, account_attributes: [:name, :phone, :website]]
     params.require(resource_name).permit(allow)
   end

end
```

Comment: Thank you, I believe this will work, but running into error on creating, `Unpermitted parameter: account`. I've got the following parameters, `"user"=>{"account"=>{"membership_name"=>"Golden"}, "email"=>"teest@test.com"}`. This is my strong parameters  `params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, account_attributes: [:membership_name])`. I also added `accepts_nested_attributes_for :account`

Comment: Make sure you updated your permit params to allow the new accounts params. I will try to update an example soon

Comment: I added the sign_up_params to the code that should be easier to follow